# Timeout issues using NGINX as a Postgres Proxy

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, proxy

I'm setting up a proxy server to intercept and forward all traffic to my Postgres database. I am using NGINX 1.19.2 to accomplish this.

The problem I have is that any queries running more than 10 minute time out. All shorter queries seem to run just fine.

Here is my entire `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

stream {
  server {
    # Allow up to 30s to establish a connection with the proxied database
    proxy_connect_timeout 30s;

    proxy_socket_keepalive on;

    listen 5432;
    proxy_pass my-server.rds.amazonaws.com:5432;
  }
}
```

I have tried several of the NGINX proxy-related configuration options (eg. `proxy_read_timeout`), however, those don't work inside of a `stream { }` context and need to be in an `http { }` context. For the purpose of connecting to Postgres, I cannot use http.

- Does anyone know what I can do to remove this 10 minute connection timeout with NGINX stream/proxy?
- Does anyone know a better alternative to accomplish what I'm trying to do that uses something other than NGINX?

  - I tried `simpleproxy` on Ubuntu, but that times out after 2 hours (yes, we have to support some long running queries, eg. `VACUUM` operations on billion+ row tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see any errors in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` that relate to these requests?

If you see `Connection reset by peer` that would mean your upstream (Postgres) is closing the connection, not Nginx.

Also, are you sure it's not your downstream?  Do you connect directly to this server or is there a Load Balancer -> Nginx -> Postgres?  The Load Balancer could be terminating the connection.

I would try setting all the timeout settings absurdly high, they would go inside the `server {}` context

```
proxy_cache_lock_timeout
proxy_connect_timeout
proxy_next_upstream_timeout
proxy_read_timeout
proxy_send_timeout

client_body_timeout
client_header_timeout
keepalive_timeout
lingering_timeout
resolver_timeout
send_timeout

# Not sure if you're using fastcgi
fastcgi_cache_lock_timeout
fastcgi_connect_timeout
fastcgi_next_upstream_timeout
fastcgi_read_timeout
fastcgi_send_timeout
```

See docs for explanation of each:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html

For things like `VACUUM` the connection might terminate but the process may still be running.  You could check running processes in Postgres to confirm when it's completed.

Comment: I checked the error logs and see `Connection reset by peer`, which speaks to Postgres cutting the connection.... Strange that I can use `simpleproxy` and that will run for so much longer without losing the connection.

Maybe NGINX does something after 10 minutes, perhaps to keep the connection alive, and that's causing Postgres to cancel the query?

Hmm... well this is a start to help me debug.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out!

The links you provided above were for the `ngx_http_*` modules, but what I needed turned out to be in the `ngx_stream_proxy_module` module here:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html

Turns out it was as simple as setting `proxy_timeout 6h` to increase the timeout. Problem solved :)